# Botium Scripts from updated Crawler userFeedback.json not generating

Tags: botium-box

When I attempt to re-run an updated userFeedback.json, with the script folder empty, I am not getting new scripts (that would include any changes made to the userFeedback.json file)

Do you have any suggestions on trouble shooting or settings/config changes?

Thanks!

Comment: can you confirm that without userFeedback.json the crawler works ? so the basic setup is fine ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to get the scripts succesfully generated so far ONLY when I run the initial Crawler docker command from powershell (which then generates BOTH the initial userFeedback.json file, the "Scripts" folder, and the expected files)  If I delete the scripts from the Scripts folder and rerun the Crawler with the new userFeedback.json file, no new Scripts are generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly when you re-run the crawler you get the same scripts as previous you updated the userFeedback.json, right?

I need some info:

- How does your command (or config) look like, which you use to run the crawler?
- What did you modified in userFeedback.json?

***Tip:** If you use DEBUG=botium-crawler* environment variable, you can get a more detailed log. E.g: `DEBUG=botium-crawler* botium-cli crawler-run ...`*

---

**Updated**

(I got some new info from the comments)

I tried it with docker as well (It's important to run it with '-it' because you will have terminal interactions):

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app/workdir -it botium/botium-cli crawler-run
```

With the command above I got this result:

[image: crawler-result]

Then I removed the scripts folder from the crawler-result, and I edit the userFeedback.json with a "test" answer on "hello" path:

```
[
  {
    "path": "hello",
    "script": "hello\n\n#me\nhello\n\n#bot\nYou said: hello\n",
    "answers": ["test"]
  },
  {
    "path": "help",
    "script": "help\n\n#me\nhelp\n\n#bot\nRecognized commands: help, fail, add to cart, show cart, clear cart, weak intent, duplicate intent, buttons, show me buttons, show me some buttons, give me buttons, picture, show me a picture, give me a picture, card, show me a card, give me a card, attachment, audio attachment, video, video attachment, Fruits, Apple, Pear, Red, Yellow, Green, Dummy button, Fruits, Apple, Pear, Red, Yellow, Green, Dummy button\n",
    "answers": []
  }
]
```

I re-run the above written docker command again, and the result is:

[image]

I hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out: 1.If I run the "crawler" directly from powershell via with no userFeedback.json file, via docker commands : docker run --rm...  Both the new "Scripts" folder and resulting scripts are generated.  --If I then delete the scripts, and even re-run the newly generated userFeedback file, no scripts are generated (I then tested modifying the userFeedback file by running the "feedback" script and adding a single new answer to one "Stuck" place.)  So the only way I'm generating scripts is by starting NEW with no existing feedback file.